# java Runtime Date syntax error - easy fix?

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to make it so each transaction is time stamped, but I'm having an issue with the date object. I keep running into a syntax error every time the program gets to the constructor. Any ideas?

Thank you so much!!!

### UPDATE: I changed it so the constructor class now says:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
Date dateobj = new Date();
```

But now I run into a null pointer expression as soon as it's called in the MainMenu method. How do I get it to work in all the methods like the array list?

```
/**
 * Bank Account
 * 
 * @author: Seth Killian
 * @version: 1.
 * @citations: All okay. Adapted online tutorials in using the scanner tools to create a menu and list array.
 */

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.Calendar;

public class BankAccount 
{ 

  private double minbalance; // Minimum allowable account balance
  private double maxdeposit; // Maximum allowable deposit
  private double balance; // Account balance 
  private double rate; // Rate of annual interest in value of percent
  private String AcctName; // Account name
  private ArrayList<String> transactions;
  public Date dateobj;
  public DateFormat df;

  /**
  * Constructor for Bank Account Class with Starting Balance
  * @param: Starting Balance
  * @return: None
  */
  public BankAccount(double startBalance) 
  {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
    Date dateobj = new Date();
    transactions = new ArrayList<String>();
    balance = startBalance;
    transactions.add("+ $" + startBalance + " Initial Balance "  + df.format(dateobj) + " Bal: $" + balance);
    minbalance = 0.25;
    maxdeposit = 5000.00;
    rate = 6; // Six percent annual interest
    AcctName = "Seth Killian";
  }

  /**
  * Main Menu which allows the user to select from options 
  * @param: None
  * @return: None
  */
  public void MainMenu()
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    switch (in.nextInt())
    {
      case 0:
       Initialize();
      case 1:
       System.out.println("Balance: $" + balance + " as of " + df.format(dateobj));
       SelectOption();

      case 2: //Make a deposit        
       double amount;
       System.out.print("Deposit Amount: $");
       amount = in.nextDouble();
       if (!(amount > 0) || (amount > maxdeposit))
        {transactions.add("* Attempted Deposit: $" + amount + " "  + df.format(dateobj));}    
       if (!(amount > 0))
        {System.out.println("Error: Amount must be greater than zero");}
       else if (amount > maxdeposit)
        {System.out.println("Error: Maximum Deposit $" + maxdeposit + ".");} 
       else
        { 
          balance += amount;
          transactions.add("+ $" + amount + " Deposit "  + df.format(dateobj) + " Bal: $" + balance);
          System.out.println("Success: Deposited $" + amount + " Balance: $" + balance);
        }
       SelectOption();

      case 3: //Make a withdrawl
       System.out.print("Withdrawl Amount: $");
       amount = in.nextDouble();
       if (!(amount > 0) || (amount > balance) || (balance-amount < minbalance))
        {transactions.add("* Attempted Withdrawl: $" + amount + " "  + df.format(dateobj));}    
       if (!(amount > 0))
        {System.out.println("Error: Amount must be greater than zero");}
       else if (amount > balance) 
        {System.out.println("Error: Insufficent Funds");}
       else if (balance-amount < minbalance)
        {System.out.println("Error: Minimum Balance $" + minbalance + ".");}
       else 
        { 
         balance -= amount;
         transactions.add("- $" + amount + " Withdrawl "  + df.format(dateobj) + " Bal: $" + balance);
         System.out.println("Success: Withdrew $" + amount + " Balance: $" + balance);
        }
       SelectOption();

      case 4: //Apply Annual Interest
       balance = balance + (balance * (rate/100.0));
       transactions.add("Interest ("+ rate + "%) "+ df.format(dateobj) + " Bal: $" + balance);
       System.out.println("Success: " + rate + "% Interest rate applied. Balance: $" + balance);
       SelectOption();

      case 5: // Print Log
       System.out.println(); 
       System.out.println("Transaction Log for " + AcctName);
       System.out.println("---------------------------------------- ");
       for(int x = 0; x < transactions.size(); x++)
        {System.out.println(transactions.get(x));}
       System.out.println("---------------------------------------- ");
       SelectOption();

      case 6: // Exits application
        System.exit(0);  

      default: // Unrecognized Selection
        System.out.println ("Error: Selection Unrecognized");
        SelectOption();
    }
  }

  /**
  * Sets the Main Menu up
  * @param: None
  * @return: None
  */
  public void Initialize()
  {
    System.out.print('\u000C'); // Clears the terminal screen
    System.out.println("Welcome " + AcctName + "!");
    System.out.println("======================================== "); 
    System.out.println("1) Check Balance\n2) Make a Deposit\n3) Make a Withdrawl\n4) Add Annual Interest\n5) Transaction Logs");
    System.out.println("\n0) Clear Screen\n6) Exit Application");
    System.out.println("======================================== "); 
    SelectOption();
  } 

  /**
  * Allows the user to make a selection.
  * @param: None
  * @return: None
  */
  public void SelectOption()
  {
    System.out.print ("Selection: ");
    MainMenu();
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to determine where the problem occurs, exactly?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your update.

Answer (score 0):

From [Class SimpleDateFormat](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ecs368-2/JavaTutorial/jdk1.2/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> Any characters in the pattern that are not in the ranges of ['a'..'z'] and ['A'..'Z'] will be treated as quoted text. For instance, **characters like ':', '.', ' ', '#' and '@'** will appear in the resulting time text even they are not embraced within single quotes.
>
> **A pattern containing any invalid pattern letter will result in a thrown exception during formatting or parsing.**

Thus your line of code `df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");` will throw an exception because of the `/`. Try putting the `/` in single quotes.

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM'/'dd'/'yy HH:mm");
```

Also like @DavidColer's answer states, you never initialize your `Date` object.

### Update

After testing it turns out that `df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");` will work without the single quotes. I should have taken a look at Oracle's documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You need to either create an instance of your `BankAccount` class by passing a double, like so `BankAccount ba = new BankAccount(100.0);` or add a default constructor in your class. Like the following.

```
public BankAccount() {
   this(0.25); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never fully initialize the date.

```
DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
```

I do not see anywhere where you use your overloaded constructor or even instantiate an instance of your bankaccount class where is it in the code?  if you are not using the overloaded constructor you should create a default constructor to instantiate your varibales.

```
public class BankAccount 
{ 

  final private double MINBALANCE; // Minimum allowable account balance
  final private double MAXDEPOSIT; // Maximum allowable deposit
  private double balance; // Account balance 
  private double rate; // Rate of annual interest in value of percent
  private String AcctName; // Account name
  private ArrayList<String> transactions;
  public Date dateobj;
  public DateFormat df;

 public BankAccount()
 {
     MINBALANCE = 25.00; // Minimum allowable account balance this should be all caps for a constant
     MAXDEPOSIT = 5000.00; // Maximum allowable deposit should also be a constant
     balance = 0.0; 
     rate = 0.0;
     AcctName = null;
     transactions = new ArrayList<String>(10);
     dateobj = new Date();
     df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
 }
```

;

like so

Comment: ... Look at my code, I don't have a "dateobj" in it, I labeled the date here "data" so for this segment of code it is absolutlely correct.. before you comment on someone else's code read it first please.